# Angular Testing: Output emitter on button click returns null for dispatchEvent

Tags: angular, unit-testing, events, jasmine

Function in my Angular component:

```
@Output() projectEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

openProjectDashboard(projectKey: string) {
    this.projectEvent.emit(projectKey);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="project-container">
  <div
    class="project-card"
    *ngFor="let project of projects"
    (click)="openProjectDashboard(project.key)"
  </div>
  ....
</div>
```

My Test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProjectGridComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    
    spyOn(component.projectEvent, "emit");
    spyOn(component, "openProjectDashboard");
});

it("should emit event", () => {
    // component.openProjectDashboard("DE365");
    // expect(component.openProjectDashboard).toHaveBeenCalled();

    const nativeElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const div = nativeElement.querySelector(".project-card");
    div.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));

    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.projectEvent.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Error I get when I run the test:

> Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of null

Comment: I think you're supposed to use https://angular.io/api/core/DebugElement instead of nativeElement.

Comment: And the click is on a div instead of a button?

Comment: I changed it to `const div = nativeElement.querySelector('.project-card');` but I still get the same error.

Comment: @mrks show place where `projects` is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `spyOn` something, you lose implementation details. You have to callThrough to still have the old implementation details.

Try:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProjectGridComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    
    spyOn(component.projectEvent, "emit");
    spyOn(component, "openProjectDashboard").and.callThrough(); // add callThrough here so the function actually runs
});

it("should emit event", () => {
    // component.openProjectDashboard("DE365");
    // expect(component.openProjectDashboard).toHaveBeenCalled();

    const nativeElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const div = nativeElement.querySelector(".project-card");
    div.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));

    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.projectEvent.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```